# Await doesn't await with firebase batches functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Well, there is a simple function that puts the loader's value to true and when the function is already finished put it to false. But there is a problem where my await from async/await `async/await` functions doesn't await the code that has a `firebase batch writes`. My code:

```js
const updateNegotiation = async title => {
  negotiationLoader.value = true
  await store.dispatch('actionUpdateNegotiation', {
  negotiation: listFromDialog.value, 
  title: title, 
  loader: negotiationLoader.value
  })
  negotiationLoader.value = false // the code doesnt await and put th loader's value to false
}
```

And here is my firebase function with `batch writes`

```js
//vuex

async actionUpdateNegotiation({commit}, deal){
        const batch = db.batch()
        const reference = db.collection('negotiations')
        .doc(moduleUser.state.user.email)
        .collection('deals')

        const setRef = reference.doc(deal.title)
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(deal.negotiation.id)

        batch.set(setRef, deal.negotiation)
        batch.update(setRef, {
          ...deal.negotiation,
          status: deal.title
        })
        const deleteRef = reference.doc(deal.negotiation.status)
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(deal.negotiation.id)

        batch.delete(deleteRef)
        
         try{
          batch.commit()
          return {
            res: false
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return{
              error,
              res: true
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` keyword only does something when the code that you call returns a promise. All you seem to have done is mark `actionUpdateNegotiation` as `async`, which is not enough to do that.

As far as I can see the only asynchronous operation inside `actionUpdateNegotiation` is the call to `batch.commit()`, so you can make the function return a promise with:

```
return batch.commit()
```

Or alternatively you can use `await`:

```
await batch.commit()
```

Comment: As frank said you are not returning your promise from `batch.commit()`. Currently the `actionUpdateNegotiation` returns immediately, as a resolved promise (async of nothing)

Comment: As frank said you are not returning your promise from `batch.commit()`. Currently the `actionUpdateNegotiation` returns immediately, as a resolved promise (async of nothing). Once you put `async` on a function it returns a promise, your function returns `{ res: false}`, which is automatically resolved as `{res: false}`;

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap your `actionUpdateNegotiation` inside a promise.

```
async actionUpdateNegotiation({commit}, deal){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            const batch = db.batch()
        const reference = db.collection('negotiations')
        .doc(moduleUser.state.user.email)
        .collection('deals')

        const setRef = reference.doc(deal.title)
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(deal.negotiation.id)

        batch.set(setRef, deal.negotiation)
        batch.update(setRef, {
          ...deal.negotiation,
          status: deal.title
        })
        const deleteRef = reference.doc(deal.negotiation.status)
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(deal.negotiation.id)

        batch.delete(deleteRef)
        
         try{
          batch.commit()
          resolve(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          reject({
              error,
              res: true
          });
        }
        });
      }
```